# ASP.NET Api Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I'm learning how to create WEB-API client

I've created some simple API:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetInfo()
        {
            return Ok("Its working!");
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult PostInfo(ClientDataDto dto)
        {

            try
            {
                someMethod(dto.IdKlienta, dto.Haslo, dto.IdZgloszenia, dto.HardwareInfo, dto.SoftwareInfo);

                return Ok("sent");
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

For now I just trying to call GET method.
When I use Fiddler with addr
localhost:someport/api/Client2 
its working

but when i try to do it by client, which code is below:

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region TESTONLY
            var debug = new XMLData();
            string HardwareInfoXML = debug.HardwareXML;
            string SoftInfoXML = debug.SoftwareXML;
            int id_zgloszenia = 20;
            int idKlienta = 25;
            //haslo = "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70";
            #endregion

            var data = new ClientDataDto() { HardwareInfo = HardwareInfoXML, SoftwareInfo = SoftInfoXML, IdKlienta = idKlienta, IdZgloszenia = id_zgloszenia };
            RunAsync(data);

        }





        private static async Task RunAsync(ClientDataDto data)
        {
            var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:7774/api/client2/");
            var url = new Uri(@"http://localhost:7774/api/client2/");

            var res1 = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var res = await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
            res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        }
```

Application closing without any info at

```
var res1 = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

I have checked to see all exceptions in Debug exception Windows, but it is just closing after trying call GetAsync
PostASync doesn't work too.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

i'm really sorry that i've posted simpe problem.
sulotion is to add .Wait() on   RunAsync(data);

```
  RunAsync(data).Wait();
```